# Microsoft Academic API: how to retrieve academic articles containing part of a title?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I would like to search for all academic papers published by a specific author and containing a set phrase anywhere in a title. I am trying to accomplish this using Academic Search Evaluate REST API. My expr currently looks like this:

```
And(Ti='[string]'...,Composite(AA.AuN='[string]'))
```

However, Ti string must contain prefix of a title and doesn't work with a string from within a title. For instance, let's assume the string is "my academic article". Ti of "my academic" would work, but "academic article" would not.

Comment: I believe, I found a solution myself. I am using W instead of Ti in the following manner: And(W='academic',W='article')

Comment: It seems like a workaround using W is not a perfect solution thus, the issue still persist.